# Azure Stream Analytics Session window abnormal behavior

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

In my Azure Stream Analytics Job, I want to create a window for each device (When data received for device). I'm using session window to maintain a separate window for each device. I want temperature threshold breach alert in every 5 minutes but sometimes behaviour is different. below is my ASA JOB query

```
SELECT
t1.DeviceId,MIN(t1.Temperature)MinTemperature,     
MAX(t1.Temperature)MaxTemperature,t2.ThresholdLimit,System.Timestamp as 
EventProcessedUtcTime,t3.EventProcessedUtcTime as LastAlertTime
,MIN(CAST(t1.MessageTime AS DateTime)) AS Window_start,
System.Timestamp AS Window_end,Count(t1.DeviceId)EventCount
INTO
[alertOutputsb]
FROM
[tsfInput] t1
INNER JOIN [device-threashold-Input] t2
ON t1.DeviceId = t2.DeviceId
LEFT OUTER JOIN [temperature-alerts-sql-Input] t3
ON t1.DeviceId = t3.DeviceId   
WHERE t1.Temperature >= Cast(t2.ThresholdLimit as float)      
GROUP BY t1.DeviceId,t2.ThresholdLimit,t3.EventProcessedUtcTime, 
SESSIONWINDOW(minute, 4, 5) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.DeviceId)
HAVING MIN(t1.Temperature) >= Cast(t2.ThresholdLimit as float)
AND MAX(t1.Temperature) >= Cast(t2.ThresholdLimit as float)
```

**InputJSON**
I'm sending Device data in every 1 minute of interval.

```
{
"DeviceId": "9327848923ABE",
"Temperature": 300.5,
"MessageTime": "2019-03-02T05:50:05.362Z"
}
```

**Output**
[image]

For Device - 9327848923ABE I got first alert in 10 minutes, after that all alert in 5 minutes window.

Comment: I think this is bug in ASA session window. I start my new job sending event for 3 devices (30 seconds of interval) and after 1 minute stop for 1 device. still, I'm getting 3 alerts in every 5 minutes and all endtime is same for all

Answer (score 0):

The [Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/session-window-azure-stream-analytics) is  way to manage session windows:

> Session windows group events that arrive at similar times, filtering
>   out periods of time where there is no data. Session window function
>   has three main parameters: timeout, maximum duration, and partitioning
>   key (optional).
>
> The following diagram illustrates a stream with a series of events and
>   how they are mapped into session windows of 5 minutes timeout, and
>   maximum duration of 10 minutes.
>
> A session window begins when the first event occurs. If another event
>   occurs within the specified timeout from the last ingested event, then
>   the window extends to include the new event. Otherwise if no events
>   occur within the timeout, then the window is closed at the timeout.
>
> If events keep occurring within the specified timeout, the session
>   window will keep extending until maximum duration is reached. Please
>   note that the maximum duration checking intervals are set to be the
>   same size as the specified max duration. For example, if the max
>   duration is 10, then the checks on if the window exceed maximum
>   duration will happen at t = 0, 10, 20, 30, etc.
>
> Thus mathematically, our session window ends if the following
>   condition is satisfied:
>
> Stream Analytics session window 5 mins timeout & 10 mins maximum
>
> When a partition key is provided, the events are grouped together by
>   the key and session window is applied to each group independently.
>   This is useful for cases where you need different session windows for
>   different users or devices.

Here is the **Syntax**:

```
SESSIONWINDOW(timeunit, timeoutSize, maxDurationSize) [OVER (PARTITION BY partitionKey)]

SESSIONWINDOW(Timeout(timeunit , timeoutSize), MaxDuration(timeunit, maxDurationSize)) [OVER (PARTITION BY partitionKey)]
```

**Explanation**:

> timeoutsize
>
> A big integer that describes the gap size of the session window. Data
>   that occur within the gap size are grouped together in the same
>   window.
>
> maxdurationsize
>
> If the total window size exceeds the specified maxDurationSize at a
>   checking point, then the window is closed and a new window is opened
>   at the same point. Currently, the size of the checking interval is
>   equal to maxDurationSize.
>
> partitionkey
>
> An optional parameter that specifies the key that the session window
>   operates over. If specified, the window will only group together
>   events of the same key.

**Examples**:
**JSON:**

```
[
  // time: the timestamp when the user clicks on the link
  // user_id: the id of the user
  // url: the url the user clicked on
  {
    "time": "2017-01-26T00:00:00.0000000z",
    "user_id": 0,
    "url": "www.example.com/a.html"
  },
  {
    "time": "2017-01-26T00:00:20.0000000z",
    "user_id": 0,
    "url": "www.example.com/b.html"
  },
  {
    "time": "2017-01-26T00:00:55.0000000z",
    "user_id": 1,
    "url": "www.example.com/c.html"
  },
  // ...
]
```

To measure how long each user sessions are, you can use the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE localinput(time DATETIME, user_id BIGINT, url NVARCHAR(MAX))
SELECT
    user_id,
    MIN(time) AS window_start,
    System.Timestamp AS window_end,
    DATEDIFF(s, MIN(time), System.Timestamp) AS duration_in_seconds
FROM localinput TIMESTAMP BY time
GROUP BY user_id, SessionWindow(minute, 2, 60) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id)
```

> The preceding query creates a session window with a timeout of 2
>   minutes, a maximum duration of 60 minutes and partitioning key of
>   user_id. This means independent session windows will be created for
>   each user_id. For each window, this query will generate output that
>   contains the user_id, the start time of the window (window_start), the
>   end of the window (window_end) and the total duration of the user
>   session (duration_in_seconds).

It's very simple, just start from the beginning if you're getting stuck.

Comment: I already go through this documentation.. the problem is, it's not working as expected.